# How I make a script execute only if i am clicking and Pressing a key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D Unity game and I need a function to only be executed when you are holding the click and pressing a key, could you help me?

I tried This

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
         transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 20));
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to execute that function over multiple frames? Because right now it will only execute `transform...` in the frame the `D` key is being pressed down. `GetKeyDown` returns `true` once, while `Getkey` returns `true` in each update loop the key is held down.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is almost correct. You are using `GetKeyDown()` which is only true for the *first* frame a key is pressed. You instead want to use `GetKey()` which is true for the entire duration a key is pressed.

```C#
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 20));
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to add the script to an object. disable or enable that object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).